# how to write trigger using after insert

Tags: trigger

I tried this code but I am getting error anyone please help on this:

```
trigger fillValue on Employee__c (after insert, after update) {
    map<decimal,contact> mapcon = new map<decimal,contact>();
    list<employee__C> ee = new list<employee__c>();
    list<contact> con = [select id,test__c from contact where test__C != null];

    if(trigger.isinsert){
        for(employee__c emp : trigger.new){
            for(contact c :con){
                if(emp.test__C == c.test__c){
                    mapcon.put(c.test__c,c);
                }
            }
        }

        for(employee__c eee : trigger.new){
            if(mapcon.size()>0){
                eee.contact__C = mapcon.get(eee.test__C).id;
            }
            ee.add(eee);
        }
        insert ee;
    }
}
```

Error:

> Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger fillValue caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: fillValue: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.fillValue: line 14, column 1

Answer (score 1):

You can not update/insert same records which are part of trigger variable `Trigger.New` in `after` trigger

You must use `before` trigger if you want to make changes in same object records on which trigger is written.

```
trigger fillValue on Employee__c (before insert, before update) {
    map<decimal,contact> mapcon = new map<decimal,contact>();
    list<employee__C> ee = new list<employee__c>();
    list<contact> con = [select id,test__c from contact where test__C != null];

    if(trigger.isinsert){
        for(employee__c emp : trigger.new){
            for(contact c :con){
                if(emp.test__C == c.test__c){
                    mapcon.put(c.test__c,c);
                }
            }
        }

        for(employee__c eee : trigger.new){
            if(mapcon.size()>0){
                eee.contact__C = mapcon.get(eee.test__C).id;
            }
            ee.add(eee);
        }       }
}
```

Comment: but i need to write trigger using after inser can u plaese give me any suggestions

Comment: What is the use case of writing trigger on after insert. As per the code given, there should not be a reason to write a trigger on after event. Also make sure it is not null `mapcon.get(eee.test__C)`

Answer (score 0):

In after insert you are trying to insert record it will surely give you error. So use @Ashwani's answer and remove the `insert ee;` line from your code. It will solve your problem.

```
if(mapcon.size()>0 && mapcon.containsKey(eee.test__C)){
       eee.contact__C = mapcon.get(eee.test__C).id;
}
```

Comment: i tried what u told but i m getting error in this line "eee.contact__C = mapcon.get(eee.test__C).id;"

Comment: @user123 update my answer.